# Mandrill - The difference between global_merge_vars and normal merge_vars

Tags: api, mailchimp, mandrill, transactional-email

I've looked at this [Mandrill knowledgebase article](http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21678522-How-do-I-use-merge-tags-to-add-dynamic-content-) over and over and cannot see any obvious explanation of what the difference is between Global Merge Vars and Merge Vars, and when I should use global vs normal.

Both global_merge_vars and merge_vars are declared within the 'message' object (as shown here in [the Mandrill API](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.html#method=send-template)), so it's not like you're declaring global_merge_vars outside the message object and then including multiple merge_vars.

Also - is there any difference between how these are declared in the template itself or do they all just use *|MERGE_VAR_NAME|* format?

Comment: I'd also be intrigued to know why the 'template_content' array key is required but can be blank (I don't really know what it's meant for either)

Comment: Alex -- Did Kaitlin answer your question? If so please accept the answer or clarify what else you need help with.

Comment: Woops! Sorry Richard - I got completely sucked into code for a while there. Kaitlin certainly put me on the right track although I did find the Mandrill API documentation a little confusing. I think it would be great if there were a few more examples on offer.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The `global_merge_vars` parameter allows you to pass global values for a particular merge tag, to be applied for all recipients in that API call by default, while `merge_vars` allows you to specify per-recipient values based on the recipient email address (this is why the `rcpt` is declared for `merge_vars`).  The content in the email or template doesn't vary - these API parameters are just distinct since they apply differently.

The `template_content` parameter is for editable regions in the template. [More details here.](http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21694286-How-do-I-add-dynamic-content-using-editable-regions-in-my-template-) Originally, Mandrill didn't support merge tags, and only supported editable regions in templates. For backwards-compatibility, `template_content` is still required when calling a template. It also helps to ensure that even if a template region isn't to be replaced, that's done explicitly by passing a blank array.

The [Mandrill KB](http://help.mandrill.com) has quite a bit of info on various topics, and you can submit a support request there if you have questions specific to your account, or in general!

Comment: Weird, I just get two empty arrays from mailchimp as a reply. Hmm.. I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: My mistake. It seems like you have to specify all sorts of message data event though the template has all this. from_email, from_name, subject and so forth.

Comment: Confusing using **rendered template** and **merge vars**, and then ***How send result html using SendMessage*** ?

Answer (score 1):

**global_merge_vars**: Give global or default values for merge tags by using the global_merge_vars parameter. These will be used in the case where a recipient doesn't have a recipient-specific value defined.

**merge_vars**: Use the merge_vars parameter to store recipient-specific values if sending to more than one recipient at a time.